# Ask PIN when app comes from Background

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance

I am trying to implement a feature in which user is asked for PIN every time it opens an App or coming from Background. After searching, I found [a solution](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html).

I have base `Activity` class from which rests are inherited. It's called `ParentActivity`. I implemented `Foreground.Listener` in my `ParentActivity` and override `onBecameForeground`, and opening `PINActivity` when it runs. Something like below

```
public abstract class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Foreground.Listener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBecameForeground() {
        openSecurityActivity();
    }

    ...

}
```

And then override this method in all child classes to call `super`

```
@Override
public void onBecameForeground() {
    super.onBecameForeground();
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Now the problem is whenever App comes in foreground, this method is running the no of times as there are child classes which are overriding this method, even when child `Activity` is not created. I tried to put a check inside `openSecurityActivity()` like below,

```
synchronized protected void openSecurityActivity() {
    if(securityPinRequired) {
        if(!isSecurityActivityOpened) {
            isSecurityActivityOpened = true;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FingerprintAndSecurityPINActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.ASK_SECURITY_PIN, true);
            intent.putExtra("isForBackgroundVerification", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

but it's still opening it twice. I can't figure out the problem. Am I missing any basic OOP concept here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: implement "Foreground" class to your application class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very silly mistake. I registered the listener inside `onStart()` but forgot to unregister it inside `onStop()`

Answer (score 1):

add android:launchMode="singleInstance" into AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I know it solves my problem, but I need to know the reason why is it opening it multiple times. +1 though